# When build my main Android app, my library bring many classes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

I have created my first library and build the library as .aar, and then deploy the .aar file into my private artifactory server.

actually the **.aar** file size is just **18kb**, but when I used the library as a dependency in my other app. my apk file size increasing by around **3.5MB**.

this is what I found on the APK Analyze.
[image]

after added my library to the app dependency, then build the apk. suddenly appear new file classes3.dex in my apk. this file bring many of packages, but that I really needed just gdn packages.

**how to exclude those all unnecessary packages/classes??**

and this is my library build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compileOnly 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compileOnly 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You lib has dependencies which also have dependencies etc...
This is what is embedded in your final apk, to ensure every API is able to run.

Now you can strip out the very necessary and remove the unnecessary using **proguard** tool. It will make sure to keep only the dependencies that are required, because somewhere in your code, there is a call to this dependency tree. It will remove the unnecessary.